# Returns the records even when the condition is not to pull the record

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables e and o1
Where table `e` has

```
Onumber        edt_image
1       AA
1       AB
1       AC
1       AA
1       AB
2       AB
3       AB
3       AA
```

And table `o1` has

```
Onumber         Obill      
1                           ABCD
2                           ABCD  
3                            ABCD
```

So when I wanted the sql to pull me Onumber with no AA and with obill “ABCD”, I mean to get

```
Onumber         edt_image
2       AB
```

But right now it pulls me

```
Onumber Edt_image
1       AB
1       AC
1       AB
2       AB
3       AB
```

The sql I used

```
Select e.onumber,o1.onumber
From e join o1 on o1.onumber=e.onumber
Where e.edt_image<>’AA’
And o1.obill=ABCD
```

Comment: I used inside a selects statement and it worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM e e1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM e
                 WHERE Onumber = e1.Onumber
                 AND edt_image = 'AA')
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM o1
            WHERE Onumber = e1.Onumber
            AND Obill = 'ABCD');
```

Comment: Thank you loads for answering! I tried it, its too slow to give me any results....is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

If you are running the query on larger result set, please consider adding indexes on Joining keys.

Word of caution, please look at the larger impact on the server before adding any indexes

```
;WITH cte_e (Onumber,edt_image) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'AA' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'AC' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'AA' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AB' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AA'
), cte_O1(Onumber, Obill)  AS
(
SELECT 1, 'ABCD' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ABCD' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'ABCD'
)
SELECT e1.onumber,
    e1.edt_image
FROM cte_e e1
INNER JOIN cte_O1 o1
    ON o1.Onumber = e1.Onumber
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte_e e2
        WHERE e1.Onumber = e2.Onumber
            AND edt_image = 'AA'
        )
```